# Angular 12.0.5 HMR is not working, not reloading modules, not reloading page (live reload), Angular 11.0.6 reloads full page

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

**Angular HMR not replacing/reloading components**

- Live Reload works for 11.0.6 and 12.1.0-next.6.
- Angular 12.0.5 does not reload at all.

> **Anyone out there who got this working and can provide a working sample app?**

## Given : A simple starter app

(from storybook https://github.com/chromaui/intro-storybook-angular-template)

### with Angular 11.0.6

Then HMR does not work as expected out of the box, but full reload does (i.e [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.)

### When updating to Angular 12.0.5

Then HMR doesn't reload anything. (no Live reload at all)

> 12.0.5 Behavior:  no reload when updating angular components.

Error in console (chrome):

```
dev-server.js:60 Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.
    at Object.5033 (dev-server.js:60)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at __webpack_exec__ (polyfills.js:12907)
    at polyfills.js:12908
    at webpackJsonpCallback (jsonp chunk loading:35)
    at polyfills.js:1
```

> After editing a component (HTML) the console is "Stuck on"  "[WDS] App hot update…"

### When updating to Angular 12.1.0-next.6"

Same result as for v11 (Then HMR does not work as expected out of the box, but full reload does (i.e [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.)

## webpack-dev-server is the cause (perhaps together with webpack 5.3)

### After some digging I realized this has to do with webpack-dev-server.

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2758

> and a solution seem to be to set the webpack target to web (instead of browser) for development. or to use a beta version of webpack-dev-server (i.e 4.0.0-beta.x)

```
"target: 'web',
```

#### Investigating the versions used by Angular build system

in  "node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/package.json" the webpack-dev-server is used.

For "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.5", webpack-dev-server version is 3.11.2

> "peerDependencies": {
> "webpack": "^5.30.0",
> "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
> },

*when updating Angular to v-next*
For "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.0-next.6",webpack-dev-server version is lower , 3.1.4, the same as in 'build-angular' v11. (probably because they realized the issue with live reloading)

> "peerDependencies": {
> "webpack": "^5.30.0",
> "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
> },

*when using Angular 11*
For "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.6"

> "peerDependencies": {
> "webpack": "^4.6.0",
> "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
> },

#### Configuring webpack (when using Angular 12.0.5 / next.6) - didn't help

Configuring according to the following resource, using @angular-builders/custom-webpack

> did't help. HELP! =D

- https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack#Custom-webpack-dev-server
- https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/packages/custom-webpack/examples/full-cycle-app/extra-webpack.config.ts

```json
//package.json
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.0",
```

```json
//angular.json
//replace "builder" in "build" and "serve"
//add customWebpackConfig with path to a new config file
//"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"
    "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "extra-webpack.config.ts",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
           },
         //...
         //replace   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
         "serve": {
           "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
```

```js
//extra-webpack.config.ts
import { Configuration } from "webpack";

export default {
    target:"web",
    // target: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "web" : "browserslist",  
} as Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

We have something similar as you presented. Did you delete package_lock, node_modules and do a fresh install?

In Angular 11.2.4 and with a fresh Angular 12.1.4 project, the setup with HRM works with no problem.
Try with "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "12.1.0", "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.4" and it should work